# Netty selector register channel with 0

Tags: netty

Recently I read netty source code. For the channel registration, I read the code below:

File name: `AbstractNioChannel.java`

```java
@Override
protected void doRegister() throws Exception {
    boolean selected = false;
    for (;;) {
        try {
            selectionKey = javaChannel().register(eventLoop().unwrappedSelector(), 0, this);
            return;
        } catch (CancelledKeyException e) {
            if (!selected) {
                // Force the Selector to select now as the "canceled" SelectionKey may still be
                // cached and not removed because no Select.select(..) operation was called yet.
                eventLoop().selectNow();
                selected = true;
            } else {
                // We forced a select operation on the selector before but the SelectionKey is still cached
                // for whatever reason. JDK bug ?
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, what does it mean for a channel registered with interest key 0 for a channel?

Answer (score 0):

It means it is registered and only notified for errors.

Comment: So, after the intialize of channel, why make such a channel registered with nofitication for errors, why not for READ or WRITE? appreciate for your help.thanks

Comment: read will be done by `read()`.

Comment: If channels are registered with interest key 0, how can selector return keys for these channels when read/write/accept/connect operation is ready? I searched the code and did not find places where key's interest opts are reset for read or accept. This confused me for a long time. Thanks in advance. @NormanMaurer

Answer (score 0):

It changed interestOps to OP_ACCEPT in functions below

```java
// AbstractNioChannel
protected void doBeginRead() throws Exception {
    ......

    final int interestOps = selectionKey.interestOps();
    if ((interestOps & readInterestOp) == 0) {
        // NioServerSocketChannel: readInterestOp == 16 
        selectionKey.interestOps(interestOps | readInterestOp);
    }
}

// NioServerSocketChannel
public NioServerSocketChannel(ServerSocketChannel channel) {
    super(null, channel, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
    config = new NioServerSocketChannelConfig(this, javaChannel().socket());
}
```